# Bundling python files inside jar for access via jython

Tags: java, python, jar, jython

In the following code I simply execute test.py from java code using jython

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  org.python.util.PythonInterpreter python = new org.python.util.PythonInterpreter();
  python.execfile("test.py");
  ...
```

My problem is test.py needs to be in same directory from where jar file is run.
I need this test.py bundled inside the jar and still be able to execute it using jython.

Approach suggested in [How do you invoke a python script inside a jar file using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551269/how-do-you-invoke-a-python-script-inside-a-jar-file-using-python) to read the script in string using  getResourceAsStream method from ClassLoader class wont work for me as my test.py imports more python scripts all bundled inside the jar.

Being new to java and jython i'm really confused.
Any help will be highly appreciated..!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply put test.py at the root of the jar, with the other scripts organized as they would be on the fs in normal python.
Then you can do something like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  org.python.util.PythonInterpreter python = new org.python.util.PythonInterpreter();
  python.exec("import test");
  python.exec("test.callsomthing()");
}
```

the import in test.py should work as normal, including importing other modules from test.py.

Comment: thanks!! do u know how to put a file at root of jar using netbeans? (sorry, i havent used jar packaging before)

Comment: got how to add at root of jar from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955299/netbeans-adding-resource-files-to-jar-file-with-ant .  Thanks a lot!! stackoverflow rocks :)

Comment: @Daniel I am facing _ImportError: no module named test_ `class test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def hello(self):
        print("Hello Python function call..!")` test.py in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the python file from the jar by using the "getResourceAsStream" of the class.

See for example: http://fiji.sc/wiki/index.php/Jython_Scripting#Distributing_jython_scripts_in_a_.jar_file

Comment: I understand that what you are suggesting is reading whole python file in a string and then execuing it as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551269/how-do-you-invoke-a-python-script-inside-a-jar-file-using-python. But problem with this is I have multiple python modules, so more python modules inside jar which are imported from this test.py which wont work in this way.

Comment: @Nullpoet, the `PythonInterpreter` class has methods to execute files, which, for a script that only declares functions and classes, is the equivalent of loading it. So load them all in the same `PythonInterpreter` instance and then execute the script that depends on the others.

An alternative is to copy all .py files to a temporary directory, and then add that directory to the classpath with: `from sys import path; path.append('/path/to/temp/dir')`