# Java Code with Jython Script

Tags: java, eclipse, jython

I am working on a Java application in which I have a Jython script written to perform a task.The code works fine and the Jython script executes when it is executed through Eclipse IDE.
But when I export the Java application to .jar file the Jython script doesn't run.

This is the directory structure I am following in Eclipse IDE:

```
application.jar
   |-- com
       |--example

           |-- package1
             |-- Function2.Java
             |-- pre_myAction.py

           |-- package2
             |-- Function1.Java
```

I am trying to call the script_function from the Function1.java in the following way:

```
PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
interp.execfile(".//com//example//pre_myAction.py");
String funcName = "function1";
PyObject someFunc = interp.get(funcName);

if (someFunc == null) {
  throw new Exception("Could not find Python function: " + funcName);
}

try {
   interp.set("DataMap", dataMap);
   someFunc.__call__(new PyString(file1));
  } catch (PyException e1) {
    LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e1.getMessage());
}

interp.cleanup();
interp.close();
```

When I tried to execute the jar from the command prompt I am getting this error:

```
File not found -//com//example//pre_myAction.py
```

And the same code gets executed in Eclipse IDE without any error.

Can anyone provide the solution or suggestion on how to execute the jython script with in a jar file.

Comment: "doesn't run" doesn't give us much to go on. What's the error message?
 How are you invoking the Jar? Have you been able to run simpler Jython scripts the same way?

Comment: When you run that jar on the command line - did you enable java for jython? Btw: your code "example" doesn't contain any code.

Comment: It looks like pre_myAction.py is in com/example/package1, not com/example. Why that would work in Eclipse IDK. EDIT: Never mind, I think I see it.

Answer (score 0):

A quick browser through the Jython code and it looks like `PythonInterpreter.execfile(String)` will look for the file in the filesystem, not the JAR. You can try looking it up using `Class.getResourceAsStream` and using the `InputStream` version of the method.

It looks like Jython will load files from the root of the JAR automatically, which gives behavior mirroring CPython. See [Bundling python files inside jar for access via jython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260311/bundling-python-files-inside-jar-for-access-via-jython/6268012#6268012) for details.